# How to play videos in recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

The app crashes when I scroll the recyclerview . I know why this happens . But I don't know how to prevent it . There are very less resources online on how to smoothly play videos in recyclerview . Facebook,instagram has done it.(even though they use react native).But what about the android studio users????..Is there a way to play crash free videos in recyclerview?

**NOTE**
The app crashes because 
VideoView extends SurfaceView, and SurfaceView doesn’t have UI synchronization buffers.If by chance  the app doesn't crashes then video that is playing tries to catch up the list when you scroll it. That looks horrible!!

Comment: post your code, stack trace of error etc

Comment: Its not a 'code specific problem'.Its hard to play videos in recyclerview in general .This is because videoview in android extends surface view class!!.

Comment: Try not playing the videos directly, for example wait for a row to be completely visible, and then set a timeout for the video to start playing and the moment it scrolls off screen pause it and clear, with insta, you have at most 2-3 rows that can be visible at a time and mostly a single row that is completely visible which reduces the load dramatically so if you could increase the size of your elements such that they take up more space, you should be able to get it to work

Comment: where should I set the time out (onBindViewHolder? or where ). Can i get a the working code.....